# Create a bytearray from hex constants

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a bunch of individual hex characters defined and I need to write them to a device serial port. How would I make a byte array from them?
For example:

```
import serial
# There is a series of predefined hex characters for talking to this device. Some
# These are just some random examples I made up 

START_BYTE = 0x03
END_BYTE = 0x10
RANDOM_BYTE1 = 0xCE
RANDOM_BYTE2 = 0xAB

# Assume I opened port and is connected
sp = serial.open()

# Now in some random method I want to write to the port the sequence of
# [START_BYTE, RANDOM_BYTE1, END_BYTE]
# How would I write this? I tried
sp.write([START_BYTE, RANDOM_BYTE1, END_BYTE])
sp.write(bytearray([START_BYTE, RANDOM_BYTE1, END_BYTE]))
# But I do not get the response on the machine I want.
```

Eventually RANDOM_BYTE will be some data bits, could be 1 to 10 bytes depending on the situation. So it would be

```
[START_BYTE, DATA_BYTES, END_BYTE]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `bytes` (or `str` under... <2.6?).

```
>>> bytes(bytearray([0x03, 0xce, 0xab]))
'\x03\xce\xab'
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!